# I want to update my component's state on vuex state change

Tags: vue.js, vuex

This is my task module which I am using in store. In this my showTaskInForm() function works perfectly fine. I can see the task appear in state.task through vue dev tools

```
const state = {
   tasks: []   // array of objects
   task: null
}

const getters = {
    task: state => state.task
};

const actions = {
    showTaskInForm({ commit, state }, taskId) {
       const task = state.tasks.filter(task => task.id === taskId);
       const taskToEdit = task.length === 1 && task[0];
       commit('showTaskInForm', taskToEdit);
   }
};

const mutations = {
      showTaskInForm: (state, taskToEdit) => (state.task = taskToEdit)
 }

export default {
    state,
    getters,
    actions,
    mutations
};
```

And this is my AddTask.vue component

```
import { mapActions, mapGetters } from "vuex";

export default {
  name: "AddTask",
  data() {
    return {
      taskName    : this.task ? this.task.name        : null,
      description : this.task ? this.task.description : null,
   };
  },
  computed: mapGetters(['task']),
};
```

As I mentioned earlier I can see the state.task in vuex is being filled but in my AddTask.vue component I need to make that if there is task in vuex so my form fields get the value of the state.task.

Help me please I am new to Vue.js.

Answer (score 0):

The object returned by the data function in your AddTask component is evaluated only once when the component is instantiated. That means that your expressions for taskName and description won't evaluate during the life cycle of the object.

You need to model taskName and description as computed properties in order to the tertiary operator to be evaluated after the dependency changes (in your case, the value of task coming from the store).

```
import { mapActions, mapGetters } from "vuex";

export default {
  name: "AddTask",
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters(['task']),
    taskName() { 
      return this.task ? this.task.name : null
    },
    description() { 
      return this.task ? this.task.description : null
    }
};
```

Comment: ok I tried what you suggested. Now when I am using v-model="taskName" on my input element the console is giving me an error that I setter for computed value is not defined. From the Vue.js doc I used this in my computed property `taskName: { get() {return this.task ? task.title : null }, set(val) { this.taskName = val  } }` but this is not working it is showing error

Comment: I am getting this warning [Vue warn]: Error in v-on handler: "RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded"

Comment: Your approach for using it in combination with v-model is correct. Only in your setter you should call a mutation of your vuex store that writes the new value into the state.